Download multiple files in Threads in Console Application
I know there are many questions on this topic and I tried all the possible solutions but still not working. Please see my problem if you can help, much appreciated.
I have created a console application that will be responsible for downloading mp4 files when as soon as they are available in the DB. So it means, I have to keep my thread running in the console application and keep checking the database every 5 minutes to see if data is available, then start downloading with multiple threads.
The list of problems I am facing here is:

When the thread starts again after 5 minutes of sleep, it processes the same records again whereas the same download might be running. Is there any way to sleep the thread for the time until all downloads get completed?

To solve the above problem, I kept a flag in DB to not process the same record again but still when the second time thread starts for newer records, it stuck the download after some interval and hangs the process.


I need help if my code is correct or not, can I get time to sleep my thread until all 5 downloads get completed, OR why is my thread stuck after 2nd trial?
Also, I encountered an error in the main Async download function as below when it stuck or hung the download, "unable to read data from the transport connection"
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
        VideoDownloadProcessor videoDownloadProcessor = new VideoDownloadProcessor();
        videoDownloadProcessor.StartProcess();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle error
    }
}

public class VideoToAudioProcessor
{   
    public async void StartProcess()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                List<Task> downloadTasks = new List<Task>();
                // Fetch records from DB in dbRecords;
                foreach (var mp4s in dbRecords)
                {
                    downloadTasks.Add(this.DownloadData(mp4Url));
                }
                
                // Wait for all download tasks to complete
                await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);
                
                Thread.Sleep(_sleepMinutes); // Thread will sleep for defined minutes and start again to check the DB to process records if any
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
    
     private async void DownloadData(string mp4Url)
     {
        string resultDownload = await DownloadFileAsync(mp4Url, videofileStoragePath);
        
        if (resultDownload == "success")
        {
            // Update in DB that download of that file is completed.
        }
     }
     
    static async Task<string> DownloadFileAsync(string fileUrl, string outputPath)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(fileUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    using (Stream contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), fileStream = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 8192, true))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                        int bytesRead;
                        long totalBytesRead = 0L;
                        long totalBytes = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength ?? -1L;

                        Console.WriteLine($"Downloading {Path.GetFileName(fileUrl)}...");

                        while ((bytesRead = await contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                            if (totalBytes > 0)
                            {
                                double percentage = ((double)totalBytesRead / totalBytes) * 100;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Progress: {percentage:F2}%");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            result = "success";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace;
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return result;
    }
}


Why does DownloadData returns a void and at the same time you want to collect the returned Task (that is void) of that method in a List? Thats weird. Besides you shouldn't use Thread.Sleep in async code. A Task isn't thread. If you need a pause look at Task.Delay.

Yes, you are right but I have to update DB flag so my DownloadFileAsync returns result after download which I am updating in the DB.

Also, it returns void because I am running multiple threads parallel to it. I might be wrong because I am not good at Threading hence posted a question.

Please suggest how to use Task.Delay and how can I get the time to delay once all my download gets finished?

When await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks); works and we can safely assume it does you shouldn't have concurrent downloads. Only if an url is in dbRecords more than once. If you somehow get a concurrent downloads after the sleeping period because one of the tasks is still running you fumbled on task handling in the DownloadData method. And the void return looks like that.

Another thing you shouldn't recreate the HttpClient constantly. You may run in Port exhaustion problem by that. HttpClient is threadsafe and easily reusable.

Okay, please let me know what do I need to update in the the code? I will have that console exe running and keep checking records to process using multithreading.

You will need to await videoDownloadProcessor.StartProcess if you hope to catch any errors.

It works after applying the suggested changes however when it is downloading files, I am getting an error as mentioned in my message "Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.    at System.Net.ConnectStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)"
